# Unity Bouncy PhysicsMat2D Not Works properly

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I Shoot a ball with force, if the force is faster than a number, everything goes well and the ball bouncing. but when the force is less than a number, it seems that bounce not works anymore and the ball move along the wall.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrNvm.jpg
(excuse me that i couldn't upload picture here)

the green one is correct for me, and the red one not correct.
I use physicsMat2D,

Friction = 0 and Bounciness = 1

Comment: Try putting the "bouncy" material on both the ball and the wall.

Comment: Not works man, a little stickness between them in forces with low numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [threshold for the speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381399/how-can-i-prevent-a-ball-from-sticking-to-walls-in-box2d) in Box2D. Try changing the velocity threshold in Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics2D
[image: Physics2D Settings]

The closer the value is to zero the smaller the impact can be to stil be counted as a bounce.

Comment: Wow, thanks man, really appreciate the answer. the game is for mobile, which number you think is better for performance and solve my problem too?

Comment: Well, this depends on how many rigidbody2Ds you have in your scene. Below the threshold they will go to sleep (get no more physics updates). I would go with a value of maybe 0.1 and see if that creates the desirable result.

Comment: thanks again. I use 0.1 too, and i think it work good. Because i really need this feature, i think 0.1 is good for this project.